# How to create a pop-up window by clicking an item in a timevis chart?

Tags: r, shiny

I've been trying to create a pop-up functionality in a `timevis` chart by using `bsModal` from `shinyBS`. I've tried  using `addItem` from reading the timevis documentation from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timevis/timevis.pdf but I can't get what I want to work. Basically, I want to click on an item in the timevis chart and get a pop-up window like what `bsModal` creates, it's not necessary to use `bsModal`, maybe something can be achieved using Javascript? Any suggestions? I'm new to both Javascript and R. Below is some code as an example of what a `timevis` chart could be which would need pop-up windows added to.

Thanks a lot,
Daniel

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)

data <- data.frame(id = 1:10, 
                   content = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), 
                   title = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), 
                   start = c("06/12/2018", "08/12/2018", "21/11/2018", "16/01/2018", "15/03/2018","09/12/2018", "20/12/2018",
                             "25/11/2018", "01/01/2018", "02/03/2018"))



ui <-fluidPage(  
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(),
                mainPanel(
      timevisOutput("timeline")
    )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$timeline <- renderTimevis({
    timevis(data)
  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using `shiny::modalDialog` and `input$appts_selected`

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)

data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  start = c("2015-04-04", "2015-04-05 11:00:00", "2015-04-06 15:00:00"),
  end = c("2015-04-08", NA, NA),
  content = c("<h2>Vacation!!!</h2>", "Acupuncture", "Massage"),
  style = c("color: red;", NA, NA)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  timevisOutput("appts"),
  div("Selected items:", textOutput("selected", inline = TRUE)),
  div("Visible window:", textOutput("window", inline = TRUE)),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$appts <- renderTimevis(
    timevis(
      data,
      options = list(editable = TRUE, multiselect = TRUE, align = "center")
    )
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$appts_selected, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Somewhat important message",
      paste(input$appts_selected, "has been selected"),
      easyClose = FALSE,
      footer = modalButton("Dismiss")
    ))
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This works great (thanks!), except it works only on the first click. Use case: the user clicks to get more details, then closes the modal to browse the timeline, then clicks again on the same box to open the same modal; nothing happens the second time (the user needs to work it around by clicking another box, then the firs box).

Comment: welcome @mayeulk. I'm not that familiar with `timevis` but it looks like there are one and double clicks. One click will open the modal and select the time point for deletion "change color to yellow and x mark appears for deletion". Double click will show the modal and can be skipped and double click again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Double-clicking behaves like single click; it does not reopen the modal for me with your code. Using R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23), shiny 1.7.2, latest dev timevis version 2.0.0.9000, R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23), tested on Rstudio and Firefox.
Maybe it is possible to have the observeEvent watch a different kind of event? (clicked, instead of selected) Or to unselect the box when leaving the modal?